# Need to be able to see the header in a tabitem of a tabcontrol

Tags: wpf, tabitem, modern-ui

We're working on a new WPF app, using the ModernUI framework for styling. Apparently one of the styles it enforces is hiding the header of a TabItem in a TabControl. For most of what we're doing that's exactly what we want, but there are times where I want to show that header to the user. Since I don't know how ModernUI is hiding/collapsing the TabItem, I don't know how to show it.

How do I show the header of a tabitem, of a tabcontrol under these circumstances?

Answer (score 0):

I got help from a co-worker. It was just an issue of styling the tabitem through the tabcontrol's resources:

```
<TabControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TabItem">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
    </Style>
</TabControl.Resources>
```

I didn't think this would work because I had problems with trying to do styles under ModernUI régime. But in this case it let me.